Maximal Linearly Independent Subsets in Finitely Generated Torsion-Free Modules Over Integral Domains
Let $R$ be an integral domain and $M$ be a finitely generated torsion-free module over $R$. Assume
$$M=\sum_{i=1}^{m}Rx_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}Ry_j\ ,$$
where $x_i, y_j \in M$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, and $1 \leq j \leq n$.
If $\{ x_{a_1}, \cdots, x_{a_s} \} \subseteq \{ x_{1}, \cdots, x_{m} \}$ and $\{ y_{b_1}, \cdots, y_{b_t} \} \subseteq \{ y_{1}, \cdots, y_{n} \}$ are maximal linearly independent subsets of $\{ x_{1}, \cdots, x_{m} \}$ and $\{ y_{1}, \cdots, y_{n} \}$ respectively, then can we conclude that $s=t$?
